# AWS elasticbeanstalk not accepting request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my node server on elastic beanstalk aws service in singapore region. But i don't know its not accepting the request which are coming from Dubai(UAE). No such logs in the logs section. I can't find any solution or reported issue anywhere. Any help with be highly appreciable. It working fine and accepting request which are coming from Pakistan. Its returning status **(blocked:mixed-content)**

Comment: Why would it matter where the requests are coming. Have you setup any firewalls?

Comment: Nope, I wasn't.

Comment: So what is exactly the problem. Your question does not provide any relevant details on it.

Comment: Actually, I have deployed my node app APIs to elasticbeanstalk its working fine when I am requesting some API from Pakistan but it's not working when we are requesting from Dubai(UAE). I have not used any firewall

Comment: server returning status is (blocked:mixed-content)